# Synchronization in Java: StringBuffer vs StringBuilder and Vector vs ArrayList

Tags: java, synchronization

This is a questions that has been asked many times, but not allways, beginners in Java (like me) can understand deeply the answers that are given.

I've been reading some books of Java, and in one of them I read that the difference between Vector and ArrayList is that the former is synchronized and the later not (the same with StringBuffer vs StringBuilder).

And the book goes explaning that «if wee need it, we can "add" synchronization to code that is not synchronized».

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8132313/stringbuilder-vs-stringbuffer-or-vector-vs-arraylist) post, Brian Roach explains that «*StringBuffer and Vector have thread synchronization that adds overhead (unless you need it, but even then there's ways to add that to the newer classes)*».

So, I have three questions:

1) If synchronization adds overhead but we can add to newer classes if we need it, why don't use StringBuffer and Vector instead of add synchronization to StringBuilder and ArrayList?

2) How can we add synchronization to a class?

3) What is the purpose of synchronization ?

Sorry for my newbie questions (I know that I must read more books), but these comcepts are not very easy to grasp.

Comment: +1 This is a good question according to me. Let's help the concept be understood.

Comment: @mtk except that it has been asked a million times before. See http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=synchronization+arraylist+vector

Comment: Let he read first what is Synchronization. It is good to ask only conceptionally difficult things. He seems not to looked at it at all and start mess everything together. This is not good question.

Comment: 3) What is the purpose of synchronization ? <--- yes, this definitley is *not* a good question.

Answer (score 4):

Synchronization has overhead associated with it and can unnecessarily slow down performance. Consider the following code snippet:

```
synchronized(this) {
   doSomething();
}
```

Whenever a thread enters a synchronized block, it has to acquire a lock. When it leaves the block it gives up the lock. This is what prevents multiple threads from entering the code block at the same time.

If the code doesn't need to be synchronized (since it will only be accessed by one thread at a time), then you can just have the code written as

```
doSomething();
```

To sum up - you generally shouldn't use the synchronized version unless you need it because it adds overhead. But you can always add synchronization using synchronized blocks (and/or locks).

Answer (score 0):

1) Because `Vector` was introduced to the java API before `ArrayList`. There is nearly no good reason to use `Vector` anymore.
Same is true for `StringBuffer` vs. `StringBuilder`

2) If you need synchronization, you can synchronize the method (or a block) where the instance is accessed/modified

Answer (score 0):

**Compatibility**. They did not want to *change* the already existing classes. So they added a variant that is not automatically synchronized. You can make an `ArrayList` synchronized by wrapping it via `List<String> list = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<String>());` into a synchronized list.

[Synchronization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synchronization_%28computer_science%29) is explained in Wikipedia. Start reading there.

Simple synchronized ArrayList example:

```
 // Class definition
 ArrayList<String> foo;

 void doSomething() {
     synchronized(foo) {
         foo.add("Foobar");
     }
 }
```

The method `doSomething` is thread safe.

Comment: As the Javadocs state, you simply use `List list = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList(...));` to add synchronization to any non-synchronized list (in this case, an `ArrayList`).

Comment: @BrianRoach then it is synchronized everywhere. It may be desirable to use a more fine grained synchronization. Plus, it is consistent to synchronize on one object, but use more than one list, avoiding deadlocks. But I add your reference to the first part.

Answer (score 0):

> 1) If synchronization adds overhead but we can add to newer classes if we need it, why don't use StringBuffer and Vector instead of add synchronization to StringBuilder and ArrayList?

IMHO, There was never a good reason to have a synchronized StringBuffer. I think it was just done for consistency with other collections.  Now the only reason to use it is when you have an API which insists on it.

Vector is more useful and while you can use Collection.synchronizedList() some APIs require it.  Since Java 5.0, some of the concurrency collections are better choices.

> 2) How can we add synchronization to a class?

Add the `synchronized` keyword to all the methods (there is more to it but in the simplest case, that is all that is needed)  You can also create a synchronized wrap like synchronizedList

> 3) What is the purpose of synchronization ?

Thread safety.